# How to setup high contrast theme in Lubuntu?

Tags: themes

I can't find a high contrast theme via "Customise look and feel".

This is something similar to the high contrast theme in MS Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu does not include a high contrast theme by default. But you can install one yourself by running `sudo apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes` from your terminal. Once the software is installed, you can open `Customize Look and Feel` to switch to that theme.

There are three aspects: widget, icon, and window border. Unfortunately, the window border aspect isn't covered by the `gnome-accessibility-themes` package. However, the default window manager in Lubuntu, Openbox, is highly customizable and most of the visual aspects can be altered by editing a plain text file, `.themerc` located here: `/usr/share/themes/openbox_theme_name/openbox-3/`. If you need specific help with that you could always ask :)

Alternatively, you could look at various sites that offer window border themes. Box-look.org is one such site. And [High Contrast BlackandWhite](http://box-look.org/content/show.php/High+Contrast+BlackandWhite?content=152406) maybe of interest to you.

[This Lubuntu page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Developers/Accessibility) has a bit about accessibility concerns.

---

Widget:

[image: Widget]

---

Icon:

[image: Icon]

---

Window border -- High Contrast BlackandWhite:

[image: Window border]